# Jquery post, response in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that on.DocumentReady posts data to another page. That page responds with some HTML encapsulated in one div tag.

My goal is to have this post response/data open in a new window.

Any hints or clues?

Here is the snippet I created from Dr. Mille's advice.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var packslip_id = 35592;
var po_no = 0018439;
var  box_no = 1;
    $.post("https://example.com/barcode/generate", { packing_slip: packslip_id, reference: po_no, total_boxes: box_no}, 
    function (data) {
        alert(data);
        var win=window.open('about:blank');
        with(win.document)
        {
            open();
            write(data);
            close();
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: I think you must forget this.  Any Popup-Blocker will block a new window without a special user-action like clicks.

Comment: Dr Molle, I am using this in a controlled environment where popups are enabled for my site...

Comment: Alec, can you give me an example of how I would use window open in combination with jquery post? I thought about it, but couldnt figure it out or find any examples online. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use the write()-Method of the Popup's document to put your markup there:

```
$.post(url, function (data) {
    var w = window.open('about:blank');
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write(data);
    w.document.close();
});
```

Comment: I think I am using what you are saying correctly..., but its not opening a popup or actually posting any data to the server. I put the new code in the in the original post.

Comment: The use looks correct. You are using an absolute URL, whats's the reason?

Comment: The url is on a separate server. I got it working now when I run it on my local mamp installation and using "Coda's" Preview function... but when I run it through safari, no data is coming up at all... I am sooo confused now. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: AJAX-Requests only work on the same Domain. Would it be an oportunity to do the thing without AJAX?

Comment: I am just gonna move the scripts onto that server... But I am really interested in knowing what you would use other than ajax... and Thanks for all your help!

Comment: See the example beyond, it will open the Popup and show the data without AJAX. It simply submit's the form directly into the popup which will be created before.

Comment: Change to: `$.post(url, data, function (data)` and it should work. The post data attribute was missing.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, I tried your suggestion, but that is not working, m getting error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined`. I even tried `var window = window.open('about:blank','popup','width=300,height=200');
  window.document.write(data);` from w3school, but getting the same error, what is wrong with it.

Comment: its getting opening in new tab.. How to open this on same tab.

Comment: `$.post(url, function (data) {  $('body').html(data); });`

Comment: Does `w.document.close();` make any difference? I tried your solution without `w.document.close();` and still works well...

Answer (score 28):

Accepted answer doesn't work with "use strict" as the "with" statement throws an error. So instead:

```
$.post(url, function (data) {
    var w = window.open('about:blank', 'windowname');
    w.document.write(data);
    w.document.close();
});
```

Also, make sure 'windowname' doesn't have any spaces in it because that will fail in IE :)

Answer (score 7):

If you dont need a feedback about the requested data and also dont need any interactivity between the opener and the popup, you can post a hidden form into the popup:

Example:

```
<form method="post" target="popup" id="formID" style="display:none" action="https://example.com/barcode/generate" >
  <input type="hidden" name="packing_slip" value="35592" />
  <input type="hidden" name="reference" value="0018439" />
  <input type="hidden" name="total_boxes" value="1" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('about:blank','popup','width=300,height=200')
document.getElementById('formID').submit();
</script>
```

Otherwise you could use jsonp. But this works only, if you have access to the other Server, because you have to modify the response.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with an ajax post and then returned using a data url:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var exportClick = function () {
        $.ajax({
           url: "/api/test.php",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "text",
           data: {
              action: "getCSV",
              filter: "name = 'smith'",
           },
           success: function(data) {
              var w = window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
              w.focus();
           },
           error: function () {
              alert('Problem getting data');
           },
        });
    }
});
```