# send data to a new window and use there

Tags: php, html, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery post, response in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825078/jquery-post-response-in-new-window)

i have a table html in a page called results.php that looks like
GenID
ENSMUSG00000098791
ENSMUSG00000023441
ENSMUSG00000047431

results.php have this function

```
<script>

function contenidoCelda() 
  {
  var table= $('#tabla_results');
  cells = $('td');
 for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++)
   {
    cells[i].onclick = function()
      {
      var formData2 = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));
      formData2.append("gen_id",(this.innerHTML));
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
      data: formData2,
      cache: false,
      processData: false, 
      contentType: false, 
      success: function(data)
      {
        alert(data);       
            window.open('test.php', '_blank');

      }
    });

       }
     }
   }

</script>
```

i whant to use the data i send in the file test.php, not to return this to results.php, use in test.php, to generate the content dinamycally.

this is test.php

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['gen_id'];
system("mkdir $data");
echo "Hola";
echo $data;
echo '<xmp>';var_dump($data);echo '</xmp>';
?>

<html>
  <link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
<body>
<form>

<p id = "testing"> Test page </p>

<?php if($data == "ENSMUSG00000047751") {echo "Good";} else {echo "Bad";}   ?>

</form>
</body>
```

so here in test.php, it must show Good, if i click that genid in the table
but it show Bad, and returns Good to results.php

the test where i create a dir, whit the genid i click works fine

what i must do?

Comment: Are you sure the directory was not already there? If the index is undefined at line 2 (`$data = $_POST['gen_id'];`) there is no way the directory can be created with that name at line 3.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "but after that"? tried refreshing the parent page?

Comment: the directory is not there, i delete after every test...

Comment: @jeroen, the problem is not solved, the echo works as i wxpect, the in the test.php, i can't work with the $data variable

Comment: But you are working with the `$data` variable, see the results of your `echo` statements.

Comment: @jeroen i edit again and say in a better way what i want to do... thx

Comment: See the duplicate question I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your $.ajax call, try setting:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "test.php",
  data: "testing123",
  cache: false,
  processData: false, 
  contentType: false, 
});
```

And see if dir test123 is created, and echoed back.

If not, then the problem is in these two lines, specifically with your definition of var formData2:

```
var formData2 = new FormData($('#formulario')[0]);
formData2.append("gen_id",(this.innerHTML));
```

Check for typing errors, such as the comma in place of the semi-colon:

```
var table = document.getElementById('tabla_results'),  <-- THIS IS A COMMA. TYPO?
cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Also, you have a mix of jQuery and javascript. Why not standardize on jQuery? For example, the two lines above would be written like this in jQuery:

```
var table = $('#tabla_results');
cells = $('td');
```

Much less typing, yes?

Also, I'm sure you have, but are you sure you've included a link to the jQuery library? Such as:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: the library is included... if i try with "testing123" i not get anything and i can't create the dir... but whit formData2 it show me the alert, and it creates the dir correctly ( and i'm not doing any other mkdir or something in other place, just here for test)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the way you define `formData2`:

```
var formData2 = new FormData($('#formulario')[0]);
```

Resulting in `formData2` not actually being FormData.

Try switching it to:

```
var formData2 = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));
```

This should solve the data problem.

**Edit:** About the edit to your question, if you want to post the results to another page, there really is no need to use ajax. Just use javascript on form submit to add the additional field with the ID (if you cannot add it like a hidden field...) and use a normal form submit.

Comment: with this i get and error with formElement

Comment: @user1843376 You have to be more specific about the error, this does not tell me much.

Comment: sorry, u edit ur comment? now i try whit var formData2 = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));
but i get the same, the dir is created with the cell content that i click, but i get nothing from the echo