# MVC 3 Calling Action method from View in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and stuck with a problem.
I have a view that allows users to select an item and then click on a button to view a report on that item. The report is a also an MVC View that expects it's model to be initialized. There is a controller action method to initialize the Model and call the report view.

So my view needs to call the report controller that initialized the model and calls the report view. The call to the report controller has to be made from a JavaScript function.

Finally, I want the report to come up in a new window while leaving the original view up.

I can call the report View directly using window.open, but that skips the report initializer and the report view crashes when it tries to access the model.

Is there a way to call a controller using window.open? 
Can I call the report controller from the report view if the model is null?
can I call the report controller from my JavaScript function in the first view?

Or how do you suggest I handle this? 
Thanks for your help!

URW

Pseudo code follows:

Below is the code for the View I am working on. It's a search form. 
The user can enter some values (or not) and click search, on the top part of the form.
the form re-displays to show search results below the search form. 
below the list of items found, are 2 buttons: One to call the ShowReport function 
and one to call a Wizard. The 2 buttons are on seperate forms, because both need to submit. 
At least that's how I see it right now. I can change that, if having 2 forms is a problem.

```
// This is the function that should call the controller to show the report
function ShowReport() 
{

    if (ReportID != null && ReportID > 0) 
    {     
      // I need to call report controller passing ReportID
    }
    else 
    { 
      alert("The Report ID is not valid. Please select a different itemand try again.");
      return; 
    }
}
```

This function stores the reportID whenever the user selects an item in the list by clicking the radio button at the beginning of the row. It also enables or disables the ShowReport and Run Wizard buttons, depending on the selected item. The report is not available for all items in the list, so this function checks to see if a report is available for the current selection and enables the SHOW Report button if a report is available.

```
function activateStart(annualWaterReportId) {

    // store the ReportID for this ID in a global 
    // in case the user wants to see the Full report
    ReportID = reportId;

    document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = false;
    if (ReportId > 0) {
        document.getElementById("viewReport").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("viewReport").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

THis function starts the report wizard when the user selects and item and clicks the RunWizard button.

```
function startAction() {

var elements = document.getElementsByName("Select");
    var id = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].checked) {
            id = elements[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (id != null) {
        document.getElementById("IDList").value = id;
        document.forms["runWizard"].submit();
    }
    else {
        alert("You must first select an item before pressing the Start Wizard button. " );
    }
}
```

THe following form displays 3 fields that will become search parameters when the user enters/selects something and clicks Search below the search fields.

```
@using ((Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "showLoadMask('Searching...')" })))
{
<table class="searchTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                Name:</div>
            <input name="searchName" type="text" value="@ViewBag.searchName" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                ID Number:</div>
            <input name="searchID" type="text" value="@ViewBag.searchID"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                Year:</div>
            <input name="searchYear" type="text" value="@ViewBag.searchYear"/>
        </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <input type="submit" class="smallButton" value="search" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

}

next comes the list of items found when the user clicked Search above. Each row is preceded by a radio button, used by the user to select a row before clicking one of the two buttons below the list.

```
<table style="width: 100%" id="searchResults">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Select Person
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th>
            State
        </th>
        <th>
            Zip Code
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var searchVM in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="Select" value="@searchVM.Number" onclick="activateStart(@searchVM.YearID) " />
                </td>
                <td>@searchVM.Number
                </td>
                <td>@searchVM.Name
                <td>@searchVM.City
                </td>
                <td>@searchVM.StateID
                </td>
                <td>@searchVM.PostalCode
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</tbody>
```

Below the search results are 2 buttons that are critical: One to show the Wizard and one to show the report. This form exists only to allow the user to access a Wizard after selecting an item in the list above.

```
<form id="runWizard" method="post" action="@ViewBag.wizardAction">
<input type="button" value="Start Wizard disabled id="startButton" onclick="startAction()" />
<input type="hidden" name="pageAction" id="pageAction" value="NEXT_ACTION" />
<input type="hidden" name="currentPage" value="3" />
```

I added this form to use for the "View Report" button so I can better control what happens when the 
button is clicked.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CallFullReport", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object>{"ReportID", }))
{
// Clicking this button should bring up the report in a new window, while leaving the current window as is.
<input type="submit" value="View Full Report" disabled id="viewReport" onclick="showReport()" />
<input type="hidden" id="ReportID" name="ReportID" value="-1"/>
}
```

The Controller I want to call is in a seperate dll, The source code is in a file called HomeController.cs the Controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult FullReport(int reportID) {
        ReportModel reportModel = null;
        try {
            reportModel = _db.Reports.Find(reportID);
        }
        catch (Exception) {
                // gen up an error message
        }

        return View(reportModel);
    }
```

Finally, there is the view the controller calls. It displays a report, using the data in reportModel
loaded by the controller I've reduced the code to the bare minimum just so I can show you something
that makes sense.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
foreach (Var item in ReportModel)
{
 <tr>
     <td class="tableLabel base">Name: </td>
     <td class="tableData base">@Item.Name</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td class="lineSpacer">&nbsp;</td></tr>
 <tr>
     <td class="tableLabel base">Address: </td>
     <td class="tableData base">@Item.Street1</td>
 </tr>
 @if (Item.Street2 != null && Item.Street2 != "") 
 {
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>@Item.Street2</td>
  </tr>
  }
  <tr>
     td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>@Item.City, @Item.StateID @Item.PostalCode</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="tableLabel base">Phones:</td><td class="tableData base">@(new HtmlString(phones))</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="tableLabel base">Email:</td><td class="tableData base"><a href="mailto:@Item.Email">@Item.Email</a></td></tr>
}
</table>
```

That's all the pseudo code I have. I've inherited all this code and I am new to MVC and everything that goes with it. Let  me know if I can provide additional info.

Thanks bunches

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You will generally get much better responses if you show some of the code that you have written to solve your problem.  It is far easier for us to suggest solutions for existing code rather than writing it from scratch.

Comment: David, I considered adding code to my post but it would be pages of code and I am afraid way more code than anyone would be willing to read.

Comment: David, I wrote up some pseudo code, most of it is original code that I reduced to bare essentials. I think it will help to show what I am after, but I don't know how to add that to my question. Can I add a file to my question?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Does my answer help you at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am very new to MVC and don't know JavaScript all that well. I am not even sure what flavor of JavaScript your post is in, Is that Ajax or Json? Can I add my pseudo code as an edit to my question?

Comment: Please feel free to.  It is a jQuery example, which is a library on top of JavaScript and is included in most MVC 3 and 4 projects by default.  Ajax is a request methodology, not a library or framework.

Comment: I've added my pseudo code as edits to my original question. Maybe that will give you a better idea if what I an after. I've heard of JQuery and it is used in my project, but it is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is so much code to post, I'm afraid I can only offer a few generic suggestions.  Hopefully they will help solve your problem.

First off, any opening of a new window MUST be done client-side.  You cannot return a new window from the server.  I know you didn't mention this in your use case, but it's important to note.

If you need the model in your report view populated, it may be easiest to call it with Ajax, passing along the data required to populate your view.  The following is a jQuery example of this borrowed from Dr. Molle https://stackoverflow.com/a/3825419/1165998

Give your button that calls the report load a unique id: loadReport

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#loadReport').on('click', function (){
        $.post(url, { ReportId: reportId },  function (data) {
            var win=window.open('about:blank');
            with(win.document)
            {
                open();
                write(data);
                close();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I think that you can do away with the Html.BeginForm for populating this data, since you want to push it to a new browser window in either case.  I would delete the CallFullReport section and just have a single button to load the report (our button with a unique id of loadReport).

Comment: David, can you elaborate on this jQuery example, now that I gave you some source code to work with? Since I don't know jQuery I am not sure where I should call my controller or even when to put the URL to open the new Window to display the report. The example in the original post does a call to $.post() before the window.open. Is that what I need to do as well?  Something like this, I think      $.post("http://MyreportSite/Home/FullReport", { ReportId:reportID },

Comment: That is exactly it.  You call to your controller, get the response and, using that response, open a new window in the callback of the post, which is what is occurring in my example.

Comment: David, since I don't need any feedback from the report once it is up, can I use the other example from the post you got the jquery from? I mean the example that does the form post to send data to the next page and then a window.open in JavaScript followed by a docucument.getElementByID. I like the simplicity of that example, but I am not sure if it could work for me.

Comment: The formatting will be really bad but here is the example I mean:    <form method="post" target="popup" id="formID"    style="display:none" action="https://example.com/barcode/generate" >
  <input type="hidden" name="packing_slip" value="35592" />
  <input type="hidden" name="reference" value="0018439" />
  <input type="hidden" name="total_boxes" value="1" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('about:blank','popup','width=300,height=200')
document.getElementById('formID').submit();
</script>

Comment: You'd have to test it to find out to be honest.  I'm not sure if it would work for you.  Perhaps set up a JSFiddle and see if it'll work?

Comment: David, looking at the jQuery example you posted yesterday, I have a question. It's not that I don't trust your answer, I am just trying to understand how this works. My question: The report I an trying to display in a new window, is usually called from a page in a different MVC app.: User clicks button, Report Controller is called, gets data from DB and call Report View. So when I call FullReport from this application, won't it call the report view rather than sending a response back to me so I can open a window?

Comment: Well, you've now highlighted another issue.  Are these MVC apps going to run into cross-domain issues?  There's the potential for that.  That aside, if you call a method returning a View, that view will be a text/html response.  As such, if you can successfully return that response, you can consume it.  The question is whether or not a response is being returned, which I would assume it is.  In short, controller actions don't do anything other than return responses.  That should be their primary job.  They can't make a view pop up in your browser on their own.

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer to my question about the controller!  I can't say it as eloquent as you, but I had realized my mistake already and then saw your answer.  Thanks for the explanation!  About the 2 Applications: They are both MVC and in the same domain, the same server, even the same web site. They are related and use the same DB and Model and share some code. So they can "talk" to each other without domain worries.

Comment: David, please take a look at the JavaScript function called ShowReport () at the very top of my pseudo code. How to I call the code from your example? $(document).ready(function () { code in here } is a function, right? Can I call it in my ShowReport function? If not, how do I assign this (JQuery?) function as the onclick event handler for my button? See the code section that starts with --- @using (Html.BeginForm("CallFullReport", "Search", --- (the 7th piece of Pseudo code above.)

Comment: Also,I think I should delete the CallFullReport form and place my button back on the RunWizard form (located just above the @using HTML.Beginform statement). A separate form for my button is not needed anymore and there is no advantage in having it. Do you agree or does it not matter?

Comment: David, something is not right with the code. I think we are missing a single quote (') on this line --- $('#loadReport).on("click", function (){ --- Resharper and VisualStudio can show me something is wrong, but neither can fix it. Also, I would prefer if I could call the JQuery function from my JavaScript function so I can check for errors and report them using alert, like I do now in ShowReport. Of course, if I can do the same test and alert the user in the JQuery function, that's fine too. Sorry for all the questions but I just don't know JQuery at all. I did mention that, didn't I?

Comment: David, I got the code to work! It took me several hours to figure out the syntax error and how to make the code a call able function, but I got it eventually and it works great! Thanks so much for your help! I could not have done it without you!

Comment: So glad you got it!  Job well done :).  And the best part? You know how you got there.  Kep up the good work.

Comment: You are correct: I don't think I will ever forget how to do this!  I also spend some time reading up on JQuery and reviewed how MVC works, and that helped me a lot to understand how this code works. But I would not have been able to get this done without your help and I really appreciate the time you took to help me. Thanks bunches! You are a good egg!

Comment: You're very welcome :).  It's always my pleasure to help people find the solution to their problem and grow in the framework.  Keep coding and keep learning!