# Pasing Javascript result to View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I got a Question, I'm really new in working with Asp.net.
I got a Javascript where I woult like to pass Data to my Controller.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#SearchButton").on("click", function () {
            var $sucheMoped = [];
            $("#tab_logic tbody tr")
                .each(function () {
                    var $Item = $(this);
                    var suchfeld = $Item.find("td > input[name='Suchfeld']").val();
                    var schluessel = $Item.find("td > select[name='Suchschluessel'] > option:selected").val();
                    alert(suchfeld + "&&&" + schluessel);
                    $sucheMoped.push({
                        Suchfeld: suchfeld,
                        Suchschluesseltyp: schluessel
                    });
                });
            window.open('@Url.Action("MainView","MainView")?SuchObject='+$sucheMoped);
        })
    </script>
```

I just would like to pass the "sucheMoped" from my javaScript to  my Controller.
My Controller is just expecting a IEnumarable of Objects with Properties Suchfeld and Suchschluesseltyp.

Anyone an idea?

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to change the way you invoke the controller action. You should stringify the array using the `JSON.stringify()` method.

So, this should look like this:

`window.open('@Url.Action("MainView","MainView")?SuchObject='+JSON.stringify($sucheMoped));`

Then, you need to create a custom model binder to bind your array with the action parameter. This is a simple array model binder for demonstration purposes only, it doesn't take into account failures or whatever, but it works in this scenario, passing the correct data, so please modify it to fit your needs.

```
public class ArrayModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var rawArray = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["SuchObject"];
        var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MyObject>>(rawArray);

        return array;
    }
}
```

What I do here, is to get the query string submitted through the URL, convert it with `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>` method and return it.

You simply need to decorate your parameter in the controller's action with the custom model binder, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search([ModelBinder(typeof(ArrayModelBinder))]IEnumerable<MyObject> SuchObject)
{
    return View(SuchObject);
}
```

**Edit**

`window.open` is useful if you want to open a new browser window. You could use it to open a new tab as well.

In order to navigate to another location without opening a new tab or window, use the `window.location` property like the following:

`window.location = '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")?SuchObject=' + JSON.stringify(array);`

Comment: Thanks, this works really well. My Last Question to that is that this window.open method always opens a new tab but i just want to override my excisting...

Comment: Then use `window.location`. Updating accordingly. If it solves your problem please upvote and mark as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery library $.getScript to call the action method in your controller and the return javascriptResult type in your action.

```
$.getScript("Home","Display")

// Home Controller
private JavaScriptResult Display()
{
    string message = "alert('Hello World');";

    return new JavaScriptResult { Script = message };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jQuery.ajax method, you can pass complex objects as `data` parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("MainView", "MainView")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 'SuchObject': $sucheMoped },
    success: function (htmlContent) {
        // write content to new window (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/23379892/1450855)
        var w = window.open('about:blank', 'windowname');
        w.document.write(htmlContent);
        w.document.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: using this my url looks like : http://localhost:49251/?SuchObject=[object%20Object]
and I'm getting no Parameter in my Controller

Comment: Edited my answer completely because you want to pass a complex object.